# Excel Formula need to Min and Max base on the Product level

Tags: excel-formula

I have this data in Excel

What formula to get the Min, Max and Ave base on the data on the left regardless on the Company.

```
Product      Company    Price
Keyboard        A        50
Keyboard        B        10
Keyboard        C        30
Mouse           A        100
Mouse           B        50
Printer         A        75
Printer         B        100
Printer         C        75
Printer         D        50
```

Let Say Product is in column  A, Company is B and Price is C

then I have this on other column D  is the Product and So on

```
Product     Min   Max   Average
Keyboard            
Mouse           
Printer
```

Answer (score 0):

Cell E2 can have this formula:

=MIN(IF(A:A=D2;C:C;""))

End the formula with Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

You can do the same to MAX and AVERAGE formulas.

Comment: Thanks Men, So many thanks(hahaha) the formula works, know I understand the meaning of Ctrl + Shift + Enter. It is an Array formula.

Answer (score 0):

Should anyone else happen to stumble cross this please consider a Pivot Table with `Product` for ROWS, and for Σ VALUES: Min of Price, Max of Price and Average of price.